# react-scripts build won't transpile template literals, app doesn't work in IE

Tags: reactjs, webpack, build, transpiler, react-scripts

We need to support IE11 with our app.
When building it with `react-scripts build` the backticks in template literals won't be transpiled, which of course doesn't work for IE.

The error appears in the chunks/vendor js file - not sure if that changes anything.

Is there any way to add some config with webpack plugins in `react-scripts`? We're on 2.1.5.

Ejecting from npm isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

So we just found out that it indeed was an error in a npm module.
Now we made a PR for it.